# Display the product category thumbnail on Woocommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails, custom-taxonomy

I would like to add on my product the image of the category parent, I manage to recover the description of my category
but not the picture

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following function based on `woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail()` source code will display any product category thumbnail from category Id, name or slug:

```
/**
 * Display product category thumbnail.
 *
 * @param mixed $product_category Category term Id, term name or term slug.
 */

function display_product_category_thumbnail( $product_category ) {
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

    if( term_exists( $product_category, $taxonomy ) ) {
        if( is_numeric($product_category) )
            $field_type = 'term_id';
        else
            $field_type = 'slug';
    } else
        return;

    $term = get_term_by( $field_type, sanitize_title( $product_category ), 'product_cat' );

    $small_thumb_size = 'woocommerce_thumbnail';
    $dimensions           = wc_get_image_size( $small_thumb_size );

    if ( $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ) ) {
        $image        = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, $small_thumb_size );
        $image        = $image[0];
        $image_srcset = function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_srcset' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $thumbnail_id, $small_thumb_size ) : false;
        $image_sizes  = function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_sizes' ) ? wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( $thumbnail_id, $small_thumb_size ) : false;
    } else {
        $image        = wc_placeholder_img_src();
        $image_srcset = false;
        $image_sizes  = false;
    }

    if ( $image ) {
        // Prevent esc_url from breaking spaces in urls for image embeds.
        // Ref: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23605.
        $image = str_replace( ' ', '%20', $image );

        // Add responsive image markup if available.
        if ( $image_srcset && $image_sizes ) {
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $term->name ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $dimensions['width'] ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $dimensions['height'] ) . '" srcset="' . esc_attr( $image_srcset ) . '" sizes="' . esc_attr( $image_sizes ) . '" />';
        } else {
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $term->name ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $dimensions['width'] ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $dimensions['height'] ) . '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

**Tested and works**

---

**Update - Addition** *(Related to your comments)*

To get the product categories from the WC_Product object `$product` and display it with its description and thumbnail, you will use:

```
global $product;

$term_ids = $product->get_category_ids();

// Loop through product category IDs
foreach( $term_ids as $term_id ){
    $term = get_term ( $term_id, 'product_cat' );

    // Product category name
    echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>';

    // Product category description
    echo '<p>' . $term->description . '</p>';

    // Product category description
    display_product_category_thumbnail( $term_id )
}
```

Tested and works

> **Note:** [`$product->get_categories();`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product.html#363-375) is **outdated and deprecated** and gives a list of formatted product categories, which is not really the best effective way.
>
> **For info:** `get_categories()` method is replaced by function `wc_get_product_category_list()`

Comment: Good! Thankyou @LoicTheAztec

Comment: In fact  to display the description I made a snippet [code]global $post, $product;
$categ = $product->get_categories();
$term = get_term_by ( 'name' , strip_tags($categ), 'product_cat' );
echo $term->description;[\code] I thought with an echo thumbnail_id it would work, but no! thank you

Comment: @Cylvain Sorry but this code, based on Woocommerce source code, is tested and works perfectly… Please don't put code in comments as it's not readable and your explanations are unclear. **I have added an addition to show you the usage at the en of my answer.**